# Modify/add to price based on custom field?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Is there a way to modify a variant's price based on a custom field in the product?

To clarify, Let's say I have a matrix field with a block that has a text input with the handle `name` and a numeric input field with the handle `price`. This is then outputs as a radio button select list in the template like "Original" and "Name". When the "Name" radio button is selected, the price is picked up from the field `price` in that matrix block. The user could then add to cart with the modified price.

Any way to do this without plugins, or is there a plugin available for this logic? I'm not PHP savvy, so any light that can be shed on this is much appreciated. Ideally there's a way to do this within the template.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use variants to handle this couldn't you?  A non-name and named variant, each with a different price.

There's no other built in way to do what you want without PHP, I think.  The PHP would not be too complex though, if you fancy adventuring into Craft plugins, which are super-useful with Commerce in general, opening up all sorts of extra possibilities.

Comment: Yes and no. The trouble is with that is this scenario;

There's a set amount of covers for a pillow, but the stuffing can be two different choices. Basically build to order, but the amount of items is based on the amount of covers.

Comment: Not fully following  perhaps, but with Multiadd you can perhaps build a form to deal with something like that- https://github.com/engram-design/MultiAdd